# ViewPager c видимыми частями соседних страниц

Tags: android

Есть ViewPager. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы в центре был один элемент и было видно слева и справа края соседних элементов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут описывается как это сделать. 
[ViewPager With Protruding Children](http://blog.neteril.org/blog/2013/10/14/android-tip-viewpager-with-protruding-children/) 
[ViewPager with previous and next page boundaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914609/viewpager-with-previous-and-next-page-boundaries)
Если вкратце, то для `ViewPager` необходимо установить 2 атрибута:

1. `setClipToPadding(false)`
2. Установить left & right padding

И в Adapter переопределить метод `PagerAdapter.getPageWith()`.

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно Вас понял, то есть вариант использовать [PageTransformer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html).
Посмотреть пример как это можно сделать можно [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20962245/pagetransformer-for-handling-the-centered-page).